# Zeppelin: Can a user run a malign command using %sh statement?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I was wondering what type of security Zeppelin provides to avoid a user run a shell command (using %sh) that, for example, would delete files from disk.

For example, take a look [here](http://www.makedatauseful.com/apache-zeppelin-on-osx-ultra-quick-start/) at the Bash interpreter test

Comment: This question is interesting but doesn't straightaway look like a programming question. :-(

Comment: The question is actually how to avoid the issue, perhaps programmatically

Comment: I agree but there are chances people might vote this down as this question doesn't provide a minimal verifiable example.